# Rerun page with new $_POST variables

Tags: php, post

I have a form which posts data to a PHP script.  Depending on the entries on the form various things happen.

In one instance I want to rerun that same page again posting new variables to it.  I would like to do this automatically without the user having to submit another form.

What would be the best way to achieve this?  I have looked around the site but suspect I am using the wrong expressions for what I want to achieve as I am coming up short.

Comment: I'm guessing you're page is not just a method in a class which you can just call again with the altered `$_POST`

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you do not require any user interaction to bring your web application to this new state, try instantiating these new `$_POST` variables as PHP variables and continue with that aspect of your code.